# VS2008 always relinking

Tags: visual-studio-2008, visual-c++

My VS2008 C++ solution consists of about 8 projects, it builds and runs successfully.

But before every run/debug session, it always relinks first.  Very annoying.

Could I get some suggestions for common causes of this, or better still some tips on working out why VS2008 thinks my freshly built solution is always out of date?

Comment: Could you post output build log?

Comment: Hi Sergius, you can find at [link](http://www.chordwizard.net/dnld/BuildLog.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Are the projects dependencies set correctly? How to test this:

1. Select the Solution (in the Solution Explorer)
2. Right-click and select "Project Dependencies..."

Comment: Are you using Precompiled Header Files (PCH)?

Comment: yes, but I'm having trouble with that as well, it's taking *longer* to compile with PCH, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810395/using-precompiled-headers-with-vs2008-takes-longer)

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest checking project files timestamp. Sometimes if you copy files from different source, they may have timestamp that is ahead of your current time. This will cause rebuilding all each time.